# parallel Stream in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, stream, hashmap

I am trying to process two maps with parallel stream in groovy.
i have two map of type HashMap of type <object, ArrayList> .
MapA and MapB.  I need to parallel stream over mapA with mapB to check if MapA's Key is present in MapB. if present then compare Value inside arraylist.

```
def Map = [:].withDefault {key -> return []}
-
-
-
//populating two maps
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (inputLine.startsWith('{"k"')) {
            def json =jsonSlurper.parseText(inputLine)
            Map.put(json.key[3],
                    [json.key[4],json.key[5]])
        }
    }

// comparing to map to check if key exists, if yes then compare value[0] of mapA to mapB's Value[0].. and then value[1] and so on. 
def compareDatastore = { mapA,mapB ->
mapA.entrySet().parallelStream().with {
    **it.forEach(entry->{**
        if(mapB.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
            if(entry.getValue().get(0)!=mapB.get(entry.getKey()).get(0) || entry.getValue().get(1)!=mapB.get(entry.getKey()).get(1))
                println "noMatch"
        }else{
            println "notFound"
        }
    })
}
}
```

How can i do this better??

sample values in map are

```
key=1245,value=[a,b]
key=1234,value=[b,a]

there will always be only two value in arraylist.
```

getting following error at foreach line in above mentioned code.

```
Caught: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    scripts/smething$_run_closure6$_closure8$_closure9.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @155: aload_3
  Reason:
    Type top (current frame, locals[3]) is not assignable to reference type
  Current Frame:
```

any help very much appreciated !!

Comment: why do you need parallel processing?

Comment: i am going to take thousands of records in-memory and compare them. I am going to stream two datasources in two maps, then compare them in memory. earlier i was streaming one datastore and was making db calls for each pin in multithreaded environment.

Comment: Without sample input this is hard to work out. Plus I don't think you need parallel processing

Comment: Plus, why do you need to use stream?

Comment: Hi tim, i have provided sample values inside which will be inside map. I have two maps having similar structure of data inside of it. i need to compare both of these map's with each other. will check if MapB contains "key" present in MapA or not.  MapA and MapB are being populated by database and pulling in thousand of records at once and doing in-memory comparison, by doing this i am reducing 50% of network calls.

Answer (score 0):

I hardcoded the input map values, but below code might do what you expect:

```
def mapA = [
    'key1': ['1', '2'],
    'key2': ['3', '4'],
    'key4': ['5', '6']
]

def mapB = [
    'key1': ['1', '2'],
    'key3': ['3', '4'],
    'key4': ['5', '7']
]

mapA.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach { entry ->
    if (mapB.containsKey(entry.key)) {
        if (entry.value != mapB[entry.key]) {
            println "'${entry.key}' key doesn't have matching value"
        } else {
            println "'${entry.key}' key has matching value"
        }
    } else {
        println "'${entry.key}' key not found"
    }
}
```

When executed, it prints the below lines:

```
'key2' key not found
'key4' key doesn't have matching value
'key1' key has matching value
```

Because of the parallel processing, the sequence of the log lines will change between executions